# Are all silent shemoneh esreis of rosh hashanah the same?

Tags: tefilla

Are the individual silent shemoneh esreis of maariv, shacharis and mincha of Rosh Hashanah identical?  Also, are the individual silent shemoneh esreis of Yom Kippur; maariv, shacharis, mincha and neilah identical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick check of a small selection of nusach Ashkenaz siddurim (Birnbaum, *Tefilloh Sefas Yisroel*, ArtScroll, Koren, Rödelheim) indicates that the 'Amidah for Rosh haShannah is the same* for all tefillot, except for Musaf.

For Yom Kippur, 'Arvit, Shacharit, and Minchah are the same, while Musaf and Ne'ilah are each unique (the latter has an identical nusach to the regular Y"K 'amidah through ברוך עושה השלום). All tefillot of Yom Kippur have viduyim, except for Ne'ilah (in most nuschaot).

---

*All Ashkenazi siddurim replace שים שלום with שלום רב for 'arvit and minchah on weekdays. Most Eastern-Ashkenazi siddurim also do so by minchah on Shabbat.

Comment: How is Neilah different from Mincha besides the Vidui?

Comment: @DoubleAA If you have petitionary insertions in the first and last brachot, they're often different (by one word?) for ne'ilah.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt what other differences, specifically, does ne'ilah contain?  And I'm referring to the Artscroll Ashkenaz edition.

Comment: @Jimmydugan, I'll have to double-check the ArtScroll, which I likely won't be able to do until Shabbos

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt that would be great, thanks.

Comment: Only slight clarification to the above is that on Yom Kippur, in keeping with the common Nusach Ashkenaz fast-day trend, *Sim Shalom* is used in both Mincha and Ne'ila. (Usually, Mincha gets *Shalom Rav*.)